# Form_for is having issues in new.html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's happening is I am getting "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" in localhost:3000. Here is my code:

```
def new
    @article=Article.new
```

for controller. 
and for new.html.erb

```
<h1> Index </h1>

<%=form_for @article do |f| %>
<p><%=f.label :title %>:<%= f.text_field :title %></p>
<p><%=f.label :body %>:<%= f.text_area :body %></p>
<p><%=f.submit "Add article" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you call `Rails.logger.debug(@article.inspect)` just before the you call the `form_for` helper and see what the value of `@article` is?

Comment: It's not showing anything up. This seems to work                  <h1> This is the Index Page </h1>
<% @article.each do |article|%>
<p><%=link_to article.title, article%></p>
 <hr/>
<%end%>
<p><%=link_to "Add Article", new_article_path%></p>                   but the code above doesn't seem too.